# What are the system requirements for GNOME Classic in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, gnome, gnome-classic

As the title says: What are the system requirements for GNOME Classic in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS? I would like an answer for GNOME Classic for Ubuntu 12.04, not for GNOME Flashback on newer releases of Ubuntu and GNOME.

Comment: there won't be really that vast differences in consuming sources between 12.04 or 13.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Minimum System Requirements**

- 1000 MHz processor (for example Intel Celeron or better);
- 1 GB RAM (system memory);
- 6 GB of free hard drive space for installation;
- either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media;
- Internet access is helpful (for installing updates during the installation process).

[Official Source](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGNOME)